# Values inserted into database show weird characters

Tags: php, mysql, database, utf-8

I am taking data in an xml feed from readability and inserting it into a database and then outputting it. The charset of the xml feed is `UTF-8`, my html page headers are also `UTF-8`. I even saved the code through my text editor as `UTF-8` and also my DB is set to `utf8_unicode_ci`. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file( "http://readability.com/christopherburton/latest/feed" );
$json = json_encode( $xml );
$array = json_decode( $json,TRUE );
$items = $array['channel']['item'];

$DB = new mysqli('localhost', 'secret', 'secret', 'secret' );
if( $DB->connect_errno ){
    print "failed to connect to DB: {$DB->connect_error}";
    exit( 1 );
}
$match = "#^(?:[^\?]*\?url=)(https?://)(?:m(?:obile)?\.)?(.*)$#ui";
$replace = '$1$2';
 
foreach( $items as $item ){
    $title = $item['title'];
    $url = preg_replace( $match,$replace,$item['link'] );
    $title_url[] = array( $title,$url );
    $sql_values[] = "('{$DB->real_escape_string( $title )}','{$DB->real_escape_string( $url )}')";
}
$SQL = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `read`(`title`,`url`) VALUES\n ".implode( "\n,",array_reverse( $sql_values ) );
if( $DB->query( $SQL ) ){
} else {
    print "failed to INSERT: [{$DB->errno}] {$DB->error}";
}
$DB->set_charset('utf8');
```

[image]

Comment: you set `$DB->set_charset('utf8');` **after** your queries, but you need to set it **before** your queries

Comment: @t.niese Someone made this for me so I'm having trouble figuring out where to put it. Should I put it after my connect?

Comment: @t.niese I put it right before $SQL and it worked. Embarrassing question. Can you put your suggestion into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the place where you put `$DB->set_charset('utf8');`

You need to tell the database in which charset you send or want to receive the data **before** you do the query.

But because you have `$DB->set_charset('utf8');` after your queries the command has no effect, to the previous queries.

If no charset is defined for the connection then the DMBS uses the charset that is set as default in the configs.
For mysql this this may be e.g. `latin1`. 
Because of that mysql thinks it received data that is encoded in e.g. `latin1` and would *convert* it to `utf8` thats why you see these strange symbols.

To solve the problem you just need ensure that `$DB->set_charset('utf8');`  is called before the queries that passes or wants to receive data in `utf8`.

For your example you could place it right after the `if( $DB->connect_errno ){}` because at that place the connection was successfully established.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive write-up. I really appreciate this.

Comment: @ChrisBurton np , as long as you take the time to elaborate the problem (e.g. showing that you checked that everything is in `utf8`) it is no problem to take the time to write an answer. And if the question is clear then it could be also helpful for other people.

Comment: @ChrisBurton one additional note: Take care when you save `php` files as `utf8` there are two ways to save them this way, with and without [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), make sure that you save the files always **without** BOM otherwise you will have 3 invisible bytes in front of your documents which could/will cause encoding/rendering problems and other unexpected behavior, because then data will already be submitted before the first `<?php` making it e.g. sometimes impossible to use sessions or cookies or to send the data compressed.

Comment: That will prove helpful with another application I am writing. I was curious when I saved (without BOM) as UTF8 what BOM was. Thanks for the additional info.